# Adjusting the width of featured area in timeline JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is it possible to adjust the width of an item's featured area only in Timeline JS (http://timeline.verite.co/) ?

I want to have a timeline that spans full page, but with a centered, fixed width featured area.